# Structural induction for multi-way (rose) trees

Tags: haskell, tree, proof, induction

Since multi-way trees can be defined as a recursive type:

```
data RoseTree a = Node {leaf :: a, subTrees :: [RoseTree a]}
```

is there a corresponding principle for performing structural induction on this type?

Comment: You mean like `Foldable` and `Traversable`?  Using `-XDeriveFunctor`, `DeriveFoldable`, `DeriveTraversable` and `import Data.Foldable` and `import Data.Traversable` you can `derive (Functor, Foldable, Traversable)` on `RoseTree` to get a generic `fold` and `traverse` for it.

Comment: Thanks. I was really asking in terms of reasoning about the structures (as described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction), rather than doing anything with the trees themselves.

Comment: @RichAshworth I find your question unclear. If you're not interested in declaring a `Foldable` or `Traversable` instance for your tree and all you want is to reason about the (abstract) data structure, why show a Haskell implementation of it?

Comment: Haskell implementation included so that this thread has a common language for talking about rose trees (I have come across a number of ways these can be represented). Agree this isn't really related to Haskell programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To state that property `P` holds for all (*) rose trees, you have to prove that

- if `l :: [RoseTree]` is a list of rose trees whose elements satisfy `P`, and `x :: a` is arbitrary, then `Note x l` satisfies `P`

The part about `P` holding on the elements of `l` is the induction hypothesis, which you can use to prove `P(Node x l)`.

There is no explicit base case here: this is because there's no explicit base case constructor. Yet, `Node x []` acts as an implicit base case for the trees,
and indeed when `l` is empty we get a base case for induction implicitly. Concretely, the hypothesis "all the elements of `l` satisfy `P`" becomes vacuously true when `l` is empty, so we get `P(Node x [])` from the induction principle above.

(*) More precisely, this principle proves `P` for every finite-depth rose tree. If you really have to consider infinite-depth ones (e.g. circular trees), you need coinduction.

Comment: Could you point me to an explanation of coinduction? Or explain it yourself?

Comment: @dfeuer The topic is quite broad. To get an overview you can check wikipedia for it, corecursion, (Knaster-)Tarski's theorem, greatest fixed points, and final coalgebras. Also, bisimilarity between processes in a process algebra is a typical notion which involves proofs by coinduction. In the specific context of functional programming and codata, I guess it can be used, but I can't point to a typical example.

Comment: @dfeuer Andy's brilliant paper from 1994 is the canonical reference for co-induction in FP, and it is highly readable: http://marcellodesales-cs-research.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ms-cs-ufcg-brazil/functional-programming/docs/gordon94tutorial.pdf

Note that in the context of Haskell, it essentially amounts to proving P(bottom) holds, since data and co-data are the same in Haskell.

Comment: could you point me to an example of induction being used like this? in the literature, I have only seen proofs using binary trees